# How to actually reduce the AWS Elasticsearch cost with Ultrawarm setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

In my ES cluster, I was having 3 master nodes and 3 data (Hot) nodes with hundreds of indices. To reduce the cost, i added 2 Ultrawarm (warm) indices and migrated all my indices to warm nodes. But it seems like the price is not depend on the storage but the instance type. Then i tried to reduce the data count from 3 to 1. It didn't allow me to do that. Can u please suggest the proper way to achieve the cost reduction from Ultrawarm instances?

Hear is the domain config
[image]

Comment: did u try reducing availability zones and data nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

when moving data from Hot to UltraWarm you incur cost because you have new UltraWarm nodes and S3 storage associated with it. However, this allows you to:

- use less EBS size
- have less data nodes (since the some of your queries will be now handled by the UltraWarm nodes)